# iOS UIImage Saving Loss of Quality?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiimageview, uiimage, rendering

I seem to be losing quality when saving an UIImage to the Photo Library. Any ideas how to fix it? Here is the important code:

```
-(IBAction)aExportPhoto:(id)sender
{
UIImage *main = [self imageWithView:imageFrame];
UIImage *water = [self imageWithView:waterFrame];
UIImage *lign = [self imageWithView:lignFrame];

CGRect fMain = imageFrame.frame;
CGRect fWater = waterFrame.frame;
CGRect fLign = lignFrame.frame;

CGSize sMain = fMain.size;
CGSize sWater = fWater.size;
CGSize sLign = fLign.size;

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(sMain);

[main drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, sMain.width, sMain.height)];
[lign drawInRect:CGRectMake(fMain.origin.x, sMain.height - 25, sMain.width - 45, 20) blendMode:kCGBlendModeNormal alpha:1.0f];
[water drawInRect:CGRectMake(sMain.width - 45, sMain.height - 35, 40, 40) blendMode: kCGBlendModeNormal alpha: 1.0f];

UIImage *newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(newImage, nil, nil, nil);
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

}
```

Here is the imageWithView method:

```
- (UIImage *) imageWithView:(UIImageView *)view
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(view.bounds.size, view.opaque, 0.0);
[view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

UIImage * img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

return img;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions` in `aExportPhoto`, like you did in `imageWithView`. `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext` uses a scale of `1` (non-retina resolution), and you want to use `0` (the scale of the device).

Comment: Any clue what the scale should be changed to? I'm trying all numbers but anything under 1 seems to lose quality and anything above 1 doesn't change the scale.

Comment: Nevermind! It works! I had read your answer wrong. Thanks for the help!